# how to debug app on real domain with using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have .NET Framework 4.6.1 app, I know just domain name of staging site "example.com" and have source code.

And I have error on staging but locally it works fine.

So I want to debug app on that domain.

Can I debug app on real domain?

I've tried something with "Attach to Process" but no success.

If I can debug, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019

Comment: @derpirscher but what if I don't have access to staging site? I know just domain name.

Comment: how did you deploy it, without access?

Comment: @derpirscher I've edited question a bit.

Comment: If you can't access the staging machine, you can't use remote debugging. If you are able to redeploy to staging, the only thing you can do is include some extra logging. But you won't be able to debug with visual studio. If you can neither redeploy nor access the staging machine there is nothing you can do ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually**, as `derpirscher` said, you should use Remote debugger to debug your project with that domain.

Make sure that your sever and your PC are under the same network. Then share(copy) the remote debugger folder from VS into the remote domain machine. Run `msvsmon.exe` on the remote server. And then you can debug the project under the domain sever.

**Anyway**, to use VS IDE to debug projects on other domain machines, you must ensure that `msvsmon.exe`(remote debugging tool) is installed and started on the remote machine, that means you must be able to access the domain computer otherwise there is nothing you can do. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019#bkmk_setup).

[Here is a document about remote debugging a c# app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2019#BKMK_setup).